# PHP artisan migrate gets could not find driver under XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-artisan, laravel-8, artisan-migrate

I use XAMPP on Windows 10, and when I run `php artisan migrate` I get this error message:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
>
> \could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables
> where table_schema = mydb and table_name = migrations and table_type =
> 'BASE TABLE')

I try to use MySQL as a database server. When I run `php -m` I get the following.

```
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
filter
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqlnd
openssl
pcre
PDO
Phar
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
SPL
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

Here is my `config/database.php`:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [
    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
    'connections' => [
        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
            'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
        ],
        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],
        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
        ],
    ],
    'migrations' => 'migrations',
    'redis' => [
        'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'phpredis'),
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'redis'),
            'prefix' => env('REDIS_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_database_'),
        ],
        'default' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_DB', '0'),
        ],
        'cache' => [
            'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', '1'),
        ],
    ],
];
```

My extensions:

```
extension=bz2
extension=curl
;extension=ffi
;extension=ftp
extension=fileinfo
extension=gd2
extension=gettext
;extension=gmp
;extension=intl
;extension=imap
;extension=ldap
extension=mbstring
extension=exif      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=mysqli
;extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=odbc
;extension=openssl
;extension=pdo_firebird
extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
;extension=pdo_pgsql
extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=pgsql
;extension=shmop

;extension=snmp

;extension=soap
;extension=sockets
;extension=sodium
;extension=sqlite3
;extension=tidy
;extension=xmlrpc
;extension=xsl
```

The database is up and running (I checked it with PHPMyAdmin).

Any idea?

Comment: You should have a module `pdo_mysql`.

Comment: I have this line in my php.ini: `extension=pdo_mysql`

Comment: Before I realized that the best OS for developing PHP is Linux, I am using [WampServer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/) and I never got any bigger problems with this. Seriously, every time when I was using XAMPP I was had problems.

Comment: Go [edit] your question and, include contents of `config/database.php` file, please

Comment: Do you install/reinstall more XAMPP instances or install/reinstall MySQL in your system?

Comment: Can you include also extensions enabled and disabled (lines with `extension` and `mysql`) from `php.ini`? I want to know what possible extensions are available and which are enabled.

Comment: @Gander No, only one instance. I updated the question with the extensions.

Comment: Uncomment also `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll` and restart server.

Comment: @Daevne could you solve this problem?